# Proving that : $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h} =1 , h=h_{1}+ih_{2} $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, exponential-function

I have used approximation :
$$e^{h_{1}}=1+h_{1}+h^2_{1}+o(h^3_{1}) $$
$$\cos(h_{2})=1-\frac{h^2_{2}}{2}+o(h^4_{2})$$
$$\sin(h_{2})=h_{2}-o(h^3_{2})$$
Using this as a definition :$ e^h = e^{h_{1}}[cos(h_{2})+i\sin(h_{2})]$ not $e^h =1+h+\frac{h^2}{2}+...$ 
to be more specific I want to calculate this limit :
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h_{1}}\cos(h_{2})}{h}=1\  ,\  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h_{1}}\sin(h_{2})}{h}=0$$ without a lot of calculation

and after a lot of tedious calculations I got the result ,but I wonder if there is a quick way to prove that this limit is equal to 1 without a lot of calculations?

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

Well you can immediately write :
$$e^h=1+h+\frac{h^2}{2}+o(h^2)$$
Hence : 
$$\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1+\frac{h}{2}+o(h)$$
And you have your result.

There is no need to separate imaginary and real part.

Comment: Actually $e^h = 1+h +o(h)$ is enough.